# How to bind a list which is a property of an object to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have two object. One of them has a property which is a list of other object. For example, I have an object `Klass` that has `students` property that contains a list of `Student` objects. I need my DataGridView to display data of students of the selected `Klass` object which is selected via a ComboBox. So, whenever I change the selected `Klass` with ComboBox, the data DataGridView will display a list of students according to the selected `Klass` object.

The simplified code written like this:

`Student` class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

`Klass` class:

```
public class Klass
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public BindingList<Student> students { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the combobox displaymember:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
            comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
```

Fill the combobox with `Klass`elements:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindingList<Klass> klassList = new BindingList<Klass>(Util.CreateMockupData());
            comboBox1.DataSource = klassList;
        }
```

Implement handler to the combobox to set the datasource of the datagridview:

```
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedKlass = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Klass;
            if (selectedKlass != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = selectedKlass.students;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the code behind.
Compare the selected item text with the keyword for loading students of the selected class and call the *Load_Grid()* method.

```
    if(cbexample.Text=="Klass1")
{
        Public Load_Grid()
        {
           //code to access the data from DB
        }
}
```

and so on.

Hope you find this useful.